# where should i place the js script files in a mvc application so jquery works well?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

the _layout.cshtml has code lines

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")    
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

by default they are placed inside the `<body>` tags by MVC. But when i leave them in this place some times `jquery` does not work. so i have decided to put those three lines in the `<head>` block in `_layout.cshtml` so the page will put styles and script files in the `<head>` as anyone would do with `php` or `jsp`. Good thing is when i put those files in `<head>` all my `jquery` started working again. But most MVC books says to place the scripts in the `<body>` block.

So where should i put them?

**updated post:**

here is my bundle file:

```
       public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
}
```

here is the layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")


</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")   
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")   
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestPage";
}

<h2>TestPage</h2>

<input type="submit" name="name" value="Click me" id="btn"/>
<div id="d1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn').click(function(){

        alert('clicked');

    });
</script>
```

here is teh [video to show that click does not work](https://youtu.be/G7HjLg727Rw)

Comment: All javascript files are recommended to be added at the end of your page, this allows the page to be rendered first and does not slow down your perceived page speed.  jQuery needs to be the first in the list of scripts added at the bottom for it to work.  Your problem was most likely that you were adding scripts to the body ABOVE the jquery link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your layout file, the script tag to load jQuery library is included at the end of the page. But there is another section called `scripts` below that. So in your individual pages ( Ex : Index,View etc..) You should be putting your javascript inside the section scripts

```
<body>
 @RenderBody()

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

And in your views (Ex : Index view)

```
@section scripts{

    <script src="~/Scripts/SomePageSpecificFile.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function(){
        // Your other js code goes here
     });
   </script>

}
```

So when razor render the page it will be

```
<body>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/SomePageSpecificFile.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        // Your other js code goes here
      }); 
   </script>
</body>
```

As long as you execute your page specific javascript which uses jQuery inside the `scripts` section ,you should be fine.

Comment: but 
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  code line includes the main jquery script file but thats where the problem is i was writting code to get checked checkboxes when i placed the 
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")   in the body area of Layout file it did not execute click events so i had to move them to the <head> then it worked

Comment: You don't need to! As long as your other script is under the scripts section, it should work.

Comment: so are you saying to this bundle
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  add only the main jquery file then all the other scripts related to bootstrap and ajax should be placed on a "Section"

Comment: include all common (Ex :jQuery/Bootstrap etc) in the layout and page specific scripts in individual pages using scripts section.

Comment: it did not work i have updated my post above with code and a video the code does not have custom script its only for a simple click event

Comment: In your TestPage.cshtml, you need to put your javascript code inside `@section scripts` as i mentioned in my answer. Also i suggest you put your click event handler code inside document.ready event`($(function(){ //code });`

Comment: assume there are several pages and its project.. does that mean i need add all the js scripts used in all pages, in to that '@section script' block and not to add any other js scripts to any of the views?

Comment: Each page / view will have it's own script section. Put that pages js inside that section.

Comment: so if i got it right a views don't have script in them written by the developer but the js scripts written by the for those pages must be placed on a separate '@section script' section on the layout file thus each page of the web application has a mapping '@section script' on the layout file an in each of those sections the developer write page's js scripts?

Comment: Just read the Answer again slowly and try it in your project. You will understand it then. 