# .net mvc select list handle on selected item event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am quite new to this net mvc thing. to understand what I am trying to do I will put an example. 
**Example** 
I have a list of clients that contains data and in my view I used a `<select>` with a `foreach` that goes through all the clients to show the data. What I am trying to do is, when a user selects a client name he would be redirected to another page where that page would get the client name as a parameter & do stuff with that. 
I tried this but I am stuck in a part

```
<select>
    @foreach (var item in Model.clients)
    {
        <option>
            @Html.Encode(item.name)
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

I know how to redirect from page A to page B like this `RedirectToAction(...)` 
 what I want to do is handle that select action to call the method in my controller & use that method to send a parameter to page B 

 
**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Fct() {
        var v = arguments[0]; //get The ID in the parameter
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "PageB")?client_id=" + v;
    }
</script>
```

I tried both lists and the one proposed by @Shyui is easier but i wanted to try something with this one

```
<select id="clients_list" onchange="Fct(this.value)">
    <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="-1">Select Name</option> <!-- Can't be selected -->
    @foreach (var item in Model.clients)
    {
        <option value="@item.ID">
            @Html.Encode(item.name)
        </option>
    }
    <option value="0">New Client</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How the redirect would be triggered? After the user has selected a client would click on a button or it would happen through JavaScript?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad to give a definitive solution, but I can give you some tips. Since you want to go to page B, you will `submit` the form. Do you have your controls in a `form` with an action to Page B? You can trigger submit `onchange` of the list with javascript if that's how you want to handle it.

Comment: @Crowcoder i can do it on a form submit but i want to do it when the user selects an item

Comment: @IKeepForgettingAccsMail, you can submit if you wire `onchange` of the list to `form.submit`. But if you don't need your whole Model, do like Shyju suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the change event of the dropdown, get the selected option and redirect the user to the next action.

```
<select id="Clients">
    @foreach (var item in Model.clients)
    {
       <option value="@item.name">@Html.Encode(item.name)</option>
    }
</select>
```

Here is the javascript(using jQuery) to handle the change event

```
$(function(){
   $("#Clients").change(function(){
     var v=$(this).val();
     window.location.href="@Url.Action("Details","Clients")?clientName="+v;      
   });
});
```

*I am using the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative path to the action method. This will work if your code is inside a razor view. But if it is inside an external js file, try the solution explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root/34361168#34361168).*

Assuming your `Details` action method in ClientsController accepts a client name

```
public ActionResult Details(string clientName)
{
  // to do : Return something
}
```

You might also consider using the html helper methods like `Html.DropdownList` to generate the dropdown element instead of doing a foreach.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Clients",new SelectList(Model.clients, "name", "name"))
```

Also you might consider passing the unique client `Id`(numeric) instead of the client name. There are limitations of query string value length in some browsers.

Comment: thank you but how do you call that jquery script ? i practised once jquery but not with .net is it in the view page?

Comment: You can put that script inside your view ( inside @section Scripts block) or an external js file.

Comment: I have done the way you showed but when i select an item in the list the script is not triggered i placed the script inside a script section & check the link you provided am i missing something?

Comment: Check your browser console for any script errors. Also you need to place your page level scripts inside a scripts section and you should have a RenderSection for scripts as mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147155/where-should-i-place-the-js-script-files-in-a-mvc-application-so-jquery-works-we/34147263#34147263) answer.

Comment: there was an error & i fixed by changing it to a javascript function, i checked the function working through an `alert("msg")` & then changed it to make it work as i intent i will post the code i have in the view (or the important part). thanks for everythnig