# I want to change the list of images based on user selection in JSON and MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to generate a list on user selection with the help of json in MVC. On page load the list will contain all the images but when the user clicks a link specifying a particular image group. Then images in that group should be shown only.

The problem is however all the images are loaded successfully on page. When I click the linkbutton for particular group it gives me a Json string with that group and redirects to Json actionresult.

Please help I'm very new to using Json.

Razor View:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ImageObj)
          {
              using (Html.BeginForm("getImageClick", "Home", new { grp = item.ImgGroup }))
              {
                  <button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" value="@item.ImgGroup" onclick="getImageClick()">@item.ImgGroup </button>
          }
          }
          <div class="clearfix"></div>


  <div class="table-bordered" style="margin-top:40px"></div>

  <div class="container" style="margin-top:10px">

      <div id="status" style="font-size:20px"></div>

      <table id="tbl" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered text-center" style="font-size:20px"></table>

      <script language="javascript">
          $("#status").text("Loading...");
          $.get("getImage", null, BindData);
          function BindData(Images) {
              var tbl = $("#tbl");
              for (var j = 0; j <= Images.length; j++) {
                  var newRow =
                      "<tr class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12'>" +
                      "<td>" + "<img src=/images/" + Images[j].Image + " " + 'alt="' + Images[j].Alt + '"' + 'style="width:200px; height:200px"' + 'class="img-thumbnail"' + " />" + "<br />" + Images[j].Description + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
                  //  +
                  //  "<tr class='col-md-4'>" +
                  //"<td class='col-md-12'>" + Images[j].Description + "</td>" +
                  //"</tr>"
                  ;

                  tbl.append(newRow);
              }
              $("#status").text("Loaded");
          }

          $.get("getImageClick", null, BindDataNew);
          function BindDataNew(ImagesNew) {
              var tbl = $("#tbl");
              for (var j = 0; j <= ImagesNew.length; j++) {
                  var newRow =
                      "<tr class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12'>" +
                      "<td>" + "<img src=/images/" + ImagesNew[j].Image + " " + 'alt="' + ImagesNew[j].Alt + '"' + 'style="width:200px; height:200px"' + 'class="img-thumbnail"' + " />" + "<br />" + ImagesNew[j].Description + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
                  //  +
                  //  "<tr class='col-md-4'>" +
                  //"<td class='col-md-12'>" + Images[j].Description + "</td>" +
                  //"</tr>"
                  ;

                  tbl.append(newRow);
              }
              $("#status").text("Loaded");
          }

      </script>
```

Controller Methods:-

```
public ActionResult getImage() //JSON Collection
       {
               Thread.Sleep(4000);
               List<ImageTbl> Images = DbContext.ImageTbls.ToList<ImageTbl>();
               return Json(Images, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }

       public ActionResult getImageClick(string grp) //JSON Collection
       {
               Thread.Sleep(4000);
               List<ImageTbl> ImagesNew = DbContext.ImageTbls.Where(x => x.ImgGroup == grp).ToList<ImageTbl>();
               return Json(ImagesNew, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

Comment: Because you have a form with a submit button and your not cancelling the default submit so your making an ajax call and a normal submit. But why in the world do your generate forms?

Comment: So how can I call the controller then? And process the post and get requests?

Comment: By using you ajax calls.

Comment: I want to use JSON for some reason in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your button has an onclick event handler, It is inside a form and clicking on that will do a normal form submit. The form's action attribute value is set to `getImageClick` and it returns JSON data. That is the reason you are seeing json data when you click on the button.

What you should do is, prevent the normal form submit behavior so that it will execute the js code which makes the ajax call and get the data and update the DOM.

Here is the unobtrusive ajax way of doing it.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ImageObj)
{
   <button class="btn grpBtn" 
       data-url="@Url.Action("getImageClick", "Home", new { grp = item.ImgGroup})">
     @item.ImgGroup
    </button>
}
```

This will add a css class `grpBtn` to the button.It also add a data attribute called `url` with value as the relative url to the getImageClick action method with the group in the query string with key `grp` Now listen to the click event on this button, read the `data-url` value and make the ajax call to that.

```
$(function(){

   $(document).on("click",".grpBtn",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();  //prevents normal link click behavior

      $("#tbl").empty(); //clear existing images

      $.getJSON($(this).data("url"),function(data){
         //loop through the items in data and build the markup for table
         $.each(data,function(a,item)
         {
           var newRow="<tr><td>"+item.Image="</td><tr>"; //Fix this as needed for your use case
           $("#tbl").append(newRow);
         });
      });
   });

});
```

Comment: You should not be editing the answer with all the code from your question! BTW, What is happening now (with the above solution i posted) when you click on the link. Are you getting any js errors ? Check your browser console.

Comment: No call is being made now. When I click the button.

Comment: do you have any js errors in your browser dev console ? Did you add the css class `grpBtn` to the links ?

Comment: I've added grpbtn class in button. These are errors I'm getting. 1. ReferenceError: $ is not defined 2. [21:52:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback: and
SecurityError: The operation is insecure. 3. TypeError: Images[j] is undefined.

Comment: This is my button as you suggested :-  <button class="btn grpBtn"
                                        data-url="@Url.Action("getImage", "Home", new { grp = item.ImgGroup})">
                                    @item.ImgGroup
                                </button>

Comment: Are you including your page level scripts inside a script section ? like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147155/where-should-i-place-the-js-script-files-in-a-mvc-application-so-jquery-works-we/34147263#34147263 ?

Comment: Yes, But It hardly made any difference when I removed my page specific Javascript. The problem is same and it is still there.

Comment: what problem ? `$  is not defined` ? It should go away as long as you jquery before loading the page level script (by following the approach posted on above link). BTW, no one asked you to remove  your page specific Javascript.

Comment: I got it now. I added  @section scripts{
                <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script><script>
.........  </script>
            } . So now the errors are:- 1. ReferenceError: $ is not defined 2. TypeError: $(...).UItoTop is not a function 3. TypeError: Images[j] is undefined 4. Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Why would you add that line! I suggest you read the link i posted in the prev comment. In short, you should load the jQuery library in your layout. and you should have a scripts section defined under that. In your page, you wrap all your page level scripts inside the scripts section. If you follow this you will not get the $ undefined error. You are getting this error because your are not loading jQuery before using it

Comment: you mean I should not add  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> inside @section scripts{ } ?

Comment: Instead add it the layout and render it with scripts. Right?

Comment: jquery might be needed in a lot of pages. So it is better to add that to the layout **once**

Comment: Ok. I added it in the bundleconfig and rendered it in layout. Added my scripts tag in views inside @section scripts. But still it says $ is undefined. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: $ is undefined Error is now gone. But the other 3 errors are still there :- 1. [23:19:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
SecurityError: The operation is insecure. 2. TypeError: Images[j] is undefined 3. Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: You can disable the browserlink in VS.In my code i am not using any code like `Images[i]`. I am using `$.each` to loop through the array coming back from the ajax call. Also my answer do not use the keyword `getPreventDefault()`. Looks like you are getting this errors from somewhere else. You need to fix that!

Comment: Can you provide me with any link which have such example. i.e. On linkbutton click some list gets called from server and is displayed in JSON. Thanks in advance.