# Display a dropdown depending on the value selected in other drop down

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am new to the MVC application an trying to add a dropdown 1 in to my page and it works fine. Now I created two more dropdowns 2 & 3, need to display the dropdown 2 or dropdown 3 depending on the selected value from the dropdown 1.

The cshtml looks like below

```
  <div>
    @{
       List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
       listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
       {
        Text = "Car",
        Value = "Car"
       });
       listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
       {
       Text = "Bike",
       Value = "Bike",
       });
       }
       @Html.Label("Vehicle")
       @Html.DropDownList("VehicleType", listItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
      <div>
      @Html.Label("Cars");
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarsList, new SelectList(Model.CarsList, "Name", "Name"), "Select Car")

     @Html.Label("Bike");
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BikeList, new SelectList(Model.BikeList, "Barcode", "Name"), "Select Bike")
     </div>
```

Now it shows all the three dropdown but I want to display the Cars dropdownlist if the Vehicle is selected as car. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the control on page load and show using `Jquery` change event.

```
//Hiding the control on page load
$(function(){
    $('#CarsList').hide();
}

//Showing it on selected index.
$('#VehicleType').on('change', function() {
    if($('#dropDownId :selected').text() == "Car")
        $('#CarsList').show();
})
```

You can do the same thing for bikes.

Answer (score 0):

we mvc developers normally do that stuff on client side. Following jquery script will do that all

```
$("#VehicleType").change(function () {

                if ($(this).val() == "Car") {
                    $("#CarsList").show();
                    $("#BikeList").hide();
                }
                else {

                    $("#CarsList").hide();
                    $("#BikeList").show();
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to hide and show the corresponding dropdown based on the selection of the first dropdown.

Since you might want to hide/show the associated labels as well, i recommend wrapping the elements in a container div.

```
<div id="car-selection">
   @Html.Label("Cars");
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarsList, 
                new SelectList(Model.CarsList, "Name", "Name"), "Select Car")
</div>

<div id="bike-selection">
     @Html.Label("Bike");
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BikeList, 
             new SelectList(Model.BikeList, "Barcode", "Name"), "Select Bike")
</div>
```

Now listen to the change event on the first dropdown and hide and show the container div's as needed.

```
$(function () {

    updateVisibility();  // Let's show the needed dropdown on page load as well

    $("#VehicleType").change(function () {
        updateVisibility();
    });

    function updateVisibility() {
        var v = $("#VehicleType").val();
        if (v === "Car") {
            $("#car-selection").show();
            $("#bike-selection").hide();
        }
        else if (v === "Bike") {
            $("#bike-selection").show();
            $("#car-selection").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju but where do I add the change event,is that going to be in the cshtml file or some where else?

Comment: You can put that in the script section of the current page or in an external javascript file. If you are putting it in the current cshtml file, make sure you are putting it inside the `@section Scripts` area so that it will be executed after loading the jQuery library.

Comment: Take a look at this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147155/where-should-i-place-the-js-script-files-in-a-mvc-application-so-jquery-works-we/34147263#34147263